# Configure Apache web server to call a app https url

Tags: apache, https, webserver, httpd.conf, proxypass

Good day,

I have a Apache server (10.8.111.67), I configure it to ProxyPass to my app server http port (10.8.1.63), its work. The thing I do in httpd.conf is just as follow:

```
ProxyPass "/mfp" "http://10.8.1.63:9080/mfp"
ProxyPassReverse "/mfp" "http://10.8.1.63:9080/mfp"
```

However, I should proxy pass to https url instead of http.

I google around, found that I need to configure something in the ssl.conf, the following is what I plan to do:

```
<VirtualHost 10.8.111.67:80>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile ???
SSLCertificateKeyFile ???
ProxyPass "/mfp" "http://10.8.1.63:9080/mfp"
ProxyPassReverse "/mfp" "http://10.8.1.63:9080/mfp"
</VirtualHost>
```

I am not sure that what cert actually I should put for `SSLCertificateFile`, is it cert from app server? I can use openssl command to download it?

And for the `SSLCertificateKeyFile`, what file I should put inside? private key from app server? May I know how to generate the private key from web server? I run ssh-keygen, I got the `id_rsa.pub` and `id_rsa`.

Kindly advise.

Kindly notify me if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to configure certificates in virtualhost just to proxy to a SSL backend.

To reverse proxy to a SSL backend you just need to make sure **mod_ssl is loaded** and that you have the directive: **`SSLProxyEngine on`** to let the reverse proxy do it to an SSL backend.

Loading certificates in virtualhost is for virtualhosts that will listen to SSL connections, mainly virtualhosts with 443 port.

So based in your description to reverse proxy to the SSL backend, aside from the mod_ssl module loaded what you want is:

```
<VirtualHost 10.8.111.67:80>
    ServerName youshouldefinethisalways.example.com
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPass /mfp https://backend-server.example.com/mfp
    ProxyPassReverse /mfp https://backend-server.example.com/mfp 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hi Ezra, I just tried, but hit error 500. The error log show me hit 502. I put the serverName as ip and port number, its ok right?

Comment: as long as the name resolves, check the error log for clues.